# Blazor Hybrid access Parent XAML Window

Tags: wpf, blazor, maui, maui-blazor, blazor-hybrid

I assume the answer will be the same for MAUI and WinForms.
I have a WPF-BlazorHybrid application.
What is the best way to access the parent XAML window and it's ViewModel from Blazor code?

Xaml page:

```
<blazor:BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot\index.html" Services="{DynamicResource services}">
            <blazor:BlazorWebView.RootComponents >
                <blazor:RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:MainRouter}"/>
            </blazor:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </blazor:BlazorWebView>
```

MainRouter:

```
@using BlazorHybrid.WPF.Views.BlazorComponents.Shared
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(MainRouter).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainBlazor)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainBlazor)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

My first actual functional Blazor page is "MainBlazor".
I want to access my xaml window and viewmodel from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Binding with component parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#binding-with-component-parameters), and [component parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#component-parameters) permit binding properties of a parent component.